# Left sidebar appearing on grouped product page

Tags: php, html, css, magento, magento-1.9

I have a minor bug/issue with my Magento site.
I've started to make a few group products, and all of the grouped product pages are broken.
It looks like 1 or both of the sidebars appear on the product page and "squeeze" the product info into the middle of the page.

I am using the "ultimo" theme.

Can anyone suggest how I can try and fix this myself?

I can probably fix it myself, if someone is able to point me to the correct file and suggest a code to fix.

[Here is the example:](http://www.ozpoolshop.com.au/lo-chlor-starver)

Comment: `I can probably fix it myself, if someone is able to point me to the correct file and suggest a code to fix.` In practice, **you won't fix it yourself**.

Answer (score 0):

To me this page looks like it is set to the base template 3-columns rather than 2-columns-right.

Since you say it only happens with grouped products have a look in your layout xml files for the handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped` then with this handle you will probably see something as follows.

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns</template></action>
</reference>
```

I guess it should be:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already tried this sadly and it didn't work.